# How to use Wildcards in VBA Array Filter Function to find non-empty strings in array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

**Overview**
I am trying to create a User Defined Function where I want to pass three strings (cell values) — Value1, Value2 and Value3, pass them to an array and then use the Join Function to concatenate them using a New-Line character and adding a custom text as prefix before each string.

**Target**

But before I join them, I want to ensure none of the parameters passed are empty strings. I am trying to use VBA Filter function to detect non-empty strings passed in the array and then join them.

**Where am I getting stuck**

However, if I pass `""` or `vbNullString` as Match parameter and set the Include parameter to 'False', the VBA **`Filter` function** is not able to detect non-empty strings. I have also used the Trim function to ensure that none of the strings passed in the array contain whitespaces.

Can I use some wildcard characters to ensure that the strings contain at least one or more characters? I have tried passing "*?" characters in the Match argument and set Include parameter to 'True' but it does not work.

**Question**

Is there a possible way to use VBA `Filter` Function, possibly with wildcard characters?

Comment: Maybe you just check the len of the passed string with `len(value1) > 0`.

Comment: I understand that there can be different methods to check if the string passed into the array is empty or not. I just want to know if there is a way within the default VBA Filter Function to identify and filter out any empty strings in an array.

Comment: Based on your post it is not that clear what you are after or what your porblem is. Please edit your post accordingly and show also the code you are having trouble with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ARINDAMMOITRA Posted a way how to resolve your (core) problem, demonstrating how to filter out empty strings via `VBA.Filter()` - feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark next the Answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Via function `GetInfotext()` I demonstrate how to

- use a `ParamArray` argument,
- filter out empty strings by help procedure `RemoveEmpty` (see a),
- concatenate custom prefixes with the found non-empty strings (see b).

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Debug.Print GetInfotext("Intro", "", "bla bla")
End Sub

Function GetInfotext(ParamArray s()) As String
    Dim tmp: tmp = s
'a) get non-empty elements
    RemoveEmpty tmp
'b) add custion prefixes
    AddPrefixes tmp, s
'c) return entire text
    GetInfotext = Join(tmp, vbNewLine)
End Function
```

*Result in VB Editor's immediate window:*

```
X: Intro
Z: bla bla
```

**Help procedures to `GetInfoText`**

The main requirement in OP is to **filter out** empty string elements; as blanks would be found in *any* element and there are no special wild cards for them, it's necessary to identify empty elements by an
unused unique character, e.g. $, so eventual negative filtering allows to remove these marked elements.

Note that the double replacement is necessary to allow to mark consecutive empty elements by the $ mark, as VBA would skip several replacing characters here.

```
Sub RemoveEmpty(arr)
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Replace(Replace(Join(arr, "|"), "||", "|$|"), "||", "|$|")
    arr = Filter(Split(tmp, "|"), "$", False)
End Sub
```

In order to check how to add the found elements to your custom prefixes, you might use the following help procedure:

```
Sub AddPrefixes(tmp, ParamArray s())
    'define custom prefixes -- change to your needs
    Dim prfx() As Variant
    prfx = Array("X: ", "Y: ", "Z: ")
    'concatenate them with passed non-empty elements
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = LBound(prfx) To UBound(prfx)
        If Len(s(0)(i)) Then tmp(ii) = prfx(i) & tmp(ii): ii = ii + 1
    Next
End Sub
```